# Colour status-completed, status-declined... and discussion, support... tags differently on the android app

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app

In the website some Meta tags are coloured differently. I think this should be replicated on the android app.

---

Thinking about it I think the required meta tags, feature-request, support, discussion and bug should also be highlighted in some way, as they are on the desktop version.

[image]

Comment: Show skweenshut!

Comment: Huh? What's that?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with a freehand circle showing the tags?

Comment: Hmm, not easily on the mobile unfortunately. Feel free to edit one in! :-)

Comment: I don't have an Android...

Comment: Hopefully someone will come along and fulfil your freehand circle craving.

Comment: I got your back, screenshot added.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: Good work! A screenshot within a screenshot too!

Comment: Just popping in to request that this should be done when the tag is used in a post as well.